# How to send an Ethereum transaction signed by a 3rd party?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, signature, sendsignedtransaction

I have crafted a transaction object with **only** the following parameters: to, value, data, nonce & chainId. I am correctly signing this transaction with a 3rd party library. And it returns me a hex string which I'm then sending using `ethers.providers.sendTransctions`: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-sendTransaction

But I'm getting this error:

```
ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unsupported transaction type: 2 (operation="parseTransaction", transactionType=2, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
```

I suspect it because the transaction signature isn't correct which in turn is due to not passing **all** the params in the transaction object.

Any help about how should I go about sending an Ethereum transaction signed by a 3rd party using Ethers.js is highly appreciated.

Comment: What library is used to sign the transaction? How is the transaction signed? It is possible that the provider or the network doesn't support type 2 transaction.